# Optimize in Z3 .NET API giving incorrect results - bug?

Tags: .net, api, optimization, z3

I am using the .NET API for Z3 and I have discovered strange behaviour (possibly bug in the optimizer) using the code bellow. When run with the class Optimize, it incorrectly finds a solution, whereas when run with the class Solver, it correctly reports infeasible. Could anyone please run the code to verify my statement? Any hint on what is going on will be highly appreciated.

Kind regards

Marek

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Z3;

namespace DS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SMTtest smt = new SMTtest();
            if (smt.Solve())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Solved");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Infeasible");
            }
        }
    }

    class SMTtest
    {
        public bool Solve()
        {
            using (Context ctx = new Context(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "model", "true" } }))
            {
                Optimize optimizer = ctx.MkOptimize();
                //Solver optimizer = ctx.MkSolver();

                int numOfTasks = 19;
                IntExpr[] time = new IntExpr[numOfTasks * 2];
                BoolExpr[] select = new BoolExpr[numOfTasks];

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
                {
                    select[i] = ctx.MkBoolConst("valid" + i.ToString());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks * 2; i++)
                {
                    time[i] = ctx.MkIntConst("time" + i.ToString());
                }

                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[1], select[0]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[0], ctx.MkLe(time[0], time[1])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[0], ctx.MkGe(time[19], time[20])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[8], select[0]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[0], ctx.MkLe(time[0], time[8])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[0], ctx.MkGe(time[19], time[27])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[0], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[0], time[1]), ctx.MkEq(time[0], time[8]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[0], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[19], time[20]), ctx.MkEq(time[19], time[27]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[2], select[1]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[1], ctx.MkLe(time[1], time[2])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[1], ctx.MkGe(time[20], time[21])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[5], select[1]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[1], ctx.MkLe(time[1], time[5])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[1], ctx.MkGe(time[20], time[24])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[1], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[1], time[2]), ctx.MkEq(time[1], time[5]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[1], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[20], time[21]), ctx.MkEq(time[20], time[24]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[3], ctx.MkEq(time[2], time[3])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[3], ctx.MkEq(time[21], time[22])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[4], ctx.MkEq(time[2], time[4])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[4], ctx.MkEq(time[21], time[23])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[2], ctx.MkOr(select[3], select[4])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkAtMost(new BoolExpr[] { select[3], select[4] }, 1));
                optimizer.Assert(select[3]);
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(time[3], ctx.MkInt(0)));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(time[22], ctx.MkInt(4)));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkNot(select[4]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[6], ctx.MkEq(time[5], time[6])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[6], ctx.MkEq(time[24], time[25])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[7], ctx.MkEq(time[5], time[7])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[7], ctx.MkEq(time[24], time[26])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[5], ctx.MkOr(select[6], select[7])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkAtMost(new BoolExpr[] { select[6], select[7] }, 1));
                optimizer.Assert(select[6]);
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(time[6], ctx.MkInt(0)));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(time[25], ctx.MkInt(1)));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[7], ctx.MkGe(time[7], ctx.MkInt(7))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[7], ctx.MkEq(time[26], ctx.MkAdd(time[7], ctx.MkInt(1)))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[9], select[8]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[8], ctx.MkLe(time[8], time[9])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[8], ctx.MkGe(time[27], time[28])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[12], select[8]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[8], ctx.MkLe(time[8], time[12])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[8], ctx.MkGe(time[27], time[31])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[8], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[8], time[9]), ctx.MkEq(time[8], time[12]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[8], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[27], time[28]), ctx.MkEq(time[27], time[31]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[10], ctx.MkEq(time[9], time[10])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[10], ctx.MkEq(time[28], time[29])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[11], ctx.MkEq(time[9], time[11])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[11], ctx.MkEq(time[28], time[30])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[9], ctx.MkOr(select[10], select[11])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkAtMost(new BoolExpr[] { select[10], select[11] }, 1));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkNot(select[10]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[11], ctx.MkGe(time[11], ctx.MkInt(7))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[11], ctx.MkEq(time[30], ctx.MkAdd(time[11], ctx.MkInt(14)))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[13], select[12]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[12], ctx.MkLe(time[12], time[13])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[12], ctx.MkGe(time[31], time[32])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[16], select[12]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[12], ctx.MkLe(time[12], time[16])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[12], ctx.MkGe(time[31], time[35])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[12], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[12], time[13]), ctx.MkEq(time[12], time[16]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[12], ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkEq(time[31], time[32]), ctx.MkEq(time[31], time[35]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[14], ctx.MkEq(time[13], time[14])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[14], ctx.MkEq(time[32], time[33])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[15], ctx.MkEq(time[13], time[15])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[15], ctx.MkEq(time[32], time[34])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[13], ctx.MkOr(select[14], select[15])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkAtMost(new BoolExpr[] { select[14], select[15] }, 1));
                optimizer.Assert(select[14]);
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(time[14], ctx.MkInt(1)));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(time[33], ctx.MkInt(5)));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[15], ctx.MkGe(time[15], ctx.MkInt(7))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[15], ctx.MkEq(time[34], ctx.MkAdd(time[15], ctx.MkInt(11)))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[17], ctx.MkEq(time[16], time[17])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[17], ctx.MkEq(time[35], time[36])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[18], ctx.MkEq(time[16], time[18])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[18], ctx.MkEq(time[35], time[37])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkEq(select[16], ctx.MkOr(select[17], select[18])));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkAtMost(new BoolExpr[] { select[17], select[18] }, 1));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkNot(select[17]));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[18], ctx.MkGe(time[18], ctx.MkInt(7))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(select[18], ctx.MkEq(time[37], ctx.MkAdd(time[18], ctx.MkInt(12)))));
                optimizer.Assert(select[0]);

                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[5], select[8]), ctx.MkLe(ctx.MkSub(time[8], time[5]), ctx.MkInt(0))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[8], select[5]), ctx.MkLe(ctx.MkSub(time[5], time[8]), ctx.MkInt(0))));

                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[3], select[7]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[3], time[26]), ctx.MkGe(time[7], time[22]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[3], select[15]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[3], time[34]), ctx.MkGe(time[15], time[22]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[4], select[10]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[4], time[29]), ctx.MkGe(time[10], time[23]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[4], select[17]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[4], time[36]), ctx.MkGe(time[17], time[23]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[6], select[11]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[6], time[30]), ctx.MkGe(time[11], time[25]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[6], select[14]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[6], time[33]), ctx.MkGe(time[14], time[25]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[6], select[18]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[6], time[37]), ctx.MkGe(time[18], time[25]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[7], select[15]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[7], time[34]), ctx.MkGe(time[15], time[26]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[10], select[17]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[10], time[36]), ctx.MkGe(time[17], time[29]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[11], select[14]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[11], time[33]), ctx.MkGe(time[14], time[30]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[11], select[18]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[11], time[37]), ctx.MkGe(time[18], time[30]))));
                optimizer.Assert(ctx.MkImplies(ctx.MkAnd(select[14], select[18]), ctx.MkOr(ctx.MkGe(time[14], time[37]), ctx.MkGe(time[18], time[33]))));


                if (optimizer.Check() == Status.SATISFIABLE)
                {
                    ctx.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }
                ctx.Dispose();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the ToString() method on the Optimize class to produce an SMT-LIB string. This makes it easier to reproduce any bugs from the command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the bug with the current version of the master branch. It reports Infeasible with the Optimize option as well. So the discrepancy between the Solver and Optimize features seems to have been fixed.

Comment: Many thanks! Indeed, I was using the version 4.4.1, the new one fixes the discrepancy. By the way, it is a pity that the optimizer in the new version lacks "fu_malik" engine, which performed best.